# Fetch data to React Native Victory charts

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, victory-charts

I managed to create an object that holds both key(service name) and value(counter of each service)
What i dont get is how i fetch the data properly to the graph, meaning that the X axis will hold the key(Service name) and Y axis will hold the value(counter)

Code of creating the object:

```
const servicesCounter = services.reduce((counterObj, service) => { //Reduce => reduce the array to a single value, then count it.
    if (counterObj.hasOwnProperty(service)) {
      counterObj[service] += 1;
      return counterObj;
    }
  
    return {
      ...counterObj,
      [service]: 1
    };
  }, {});
```

Console Log:

```
Service Counter =>  Object {
  "clean": 4,
  "haircut": 3,
  "wash": 1,
}
```

Victory Pie:

```
  data={[
    { x: "One" /*Here i need to present the key(service name) */ , y: 2 /*Here i need to present the value(counter)*/},
    { x: "Two", y: 4 },
    { x: "Three", y: 3 }
  ]}
```

Firestore query to get the service names:

```
  useEffect(() => { //Query to get the services from database and count them to later use.
    firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("confirmed-appointments").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      let arrayofServices = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        arrayofServices.push(doc.data().serviceType)
      })
      //console.log("Array of services ", arrayofServices);
      setServices(arrayofServices);
    })
    
  }, [])
```

Any Suggestions that will make my life easier please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object.entries and iterate through the properties and create an array for the chart and use it in the chart. you can run the snippet below.

```js
const data = {
  "clean": 4,
  "haircut": 3,
  "wash": 1,
};

const arr = new Array();

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  arr.push({x:key,y:value});
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: by creating const data im assuming that i know the keys and values. actually im getting the data from Firestore, so if the user add a service , i will need to update const data manually.
Im editing the post with the firestore query

Comment: no it can be any object i just gave a sample, you can use any object which has the same format of key and value and convert it to the way you want

Comment: i will try to match your code to mine and will update here my results

Comment: ok so you have an array 'arrayofServices' which you want to convert to that form right ? may i know whats not working ?

Comment: I tried your way and do as u suggested, but when i pass the data to the Victory Pie like this : data={pieData} 
i got this red warning: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `VictoryPie`, expected `array`.

Comment: you should pass the arr not data

Comment: My bad, as usual. cant focus on this hour haha sorry man

Comment: Hope you got it sorted :)